# pandas `styler.bar` method - different color for values above threshold

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I have the following DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df["Value"] =[1,2,3,4,5]
```

and I want to generate bars for `Value` column in such a way that up to value `3` the color of the bar is green and the part of the bar above 3 is red. How can I do that? Above fails:

```
df.style.bar(subset = ["Value"], color = ["green", "red"])
```

**EDIT**
Amy's answer doesnt work properly:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to declare each condition like this:

```py
df2 = df.style.bar(subset=["Value"], color="green", vmin=0, vmax=3).bar(
    subset=["Value"], color="red", vmin=4, vmax=5
)
df2.show()
```

Comment: It doesnt work in the way I need (see my edited question)

Comment: in your screenshot, the vmin =3 .. can you try: subset=["Value"], color="red", vmin=4, vmax=5

Comment: It's the same - the entire 5th row is red instead of being green up to 3 and then red

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution would be using a specific function to make a "color" column, then pass that to the plotting function:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Value'] = [1,2,3,4,5]
df.index = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'] #to make the plot more clear


def colorize(row):
    if row.Value > 3:
        return 'red'
    return 'green'

df['color'] = df.apply(colorize, axis=1)
```

The final DataFrame looks like this:

```
   Value  color
A      1  green
B      2  green
C      3  green
D      4    red
E      5    red
```

Now the plotting:

```
df.Value.plot(kind='barh', color=df.color)
```

[image]